# asp как задать определенный string.Format для Literal`a

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

На форме есть определенный `<asp:Literal>` в котором находиться дата, как задать этому литералу определенный формат? Пробую так, не получается:

```
Literal2.Text = string.Format("{0:d}", Literal2);
```

Прописываю эту строку в методе Page_Load().

Comment: а данные как присваиваете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я вас правильно понял, попробуйте так:

```
Literal2.Text = string.Format("{0:d}", Convert.ToDateTime(Literal2.Text));
```

Comment: Все оказалось так просто) Спасибо!